# Why am I getting lifted/5.1 undefined error while using formlets?

Tags: undefined, racket, formlets

I am having trouble with an error I keep getting while trying to use formlets in racket. It says:

```
; lifted/5.1: undefined;
;  cannot reference an identifier before its definition
;   in module: top-level
;   internal name: lifted/5.1
```

Nothing in my code is named "lifted" or "5.1" or any combination of the two. I am thinking that this is something inside the black box of formlets that I'm running up against, but I don't know what.

```
; set up
(require web-server/servlet web-server/servlet-env)
(require web-server/formlets)

; body of program
(define simpleformlet 
   (formlet 
     (#%#
       "Name: " ,{input-string . => . name}
       "Number: " ,{input-int . => . number})
       (name number)))

(define (start request)
  (showpage request))

(define (showpage request)
  (define (responsegen embed/url)
    (response/xexpr
      `(html
         (head (title "App3"))
         (body (h1 "Let's try this...")
               (form
                 ([action ,(embed/url actionhandler)] 
                  [method "POST"])
                 ,@(formlet-display simpleformlet)
                 (input ([type "submit"])))))))

  (define (actionhandler request)
    (define-values (name number)
               (formlet-process simpleformlet request))
    (response/xexpr
      `(html
         (head (title "Alright!"))
         (body (h2 "name")
               (p ,name)
               (h2 "number")
               (p ,number)))))
  (send/suspend/dispatch responsegen))

; run it!
(serve/servlet start
    #:servlet-regexp #rx""
    #:servlet-path "/form")
```

Comment: We need a minimal example that produces that error in order to give meaningful advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the line

```
#lang racket
```

at the top of your program. Used "Determine language from source" in the lower, left corner of DrRacket. And ran your program. A browser window opened and I was able to enter a name and a number, before I got a sensible error.

I am using Racket version 6.12, so if you are using an older version of Racket, then upgrade and try again.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm using SublimeText3 however - and the error still occurs using that. DrRacket does seem to fix it, but I'd rather use SublimeText if possible. Do you know how to determine language from source there?

Comment: You still need to use `#lang racket` as the first line. Which racket plugin for Sublime Text are you using?

Comment: I just figured out - I can use the longhand version of (module name racket ... ) to work. And I did try #lang racket, but that didn't seem to do anything. I am using the racket plugin mentioned in the racket documentation - is there another one?

Comment: Don't know. I see that @follesoe has not updated the Sublime package in 4 years. If it works that is fine. If you run into problems, then check in DrRacket which is maintained by the Racket project - or try in racket-mode in Emacs, which is also up-to-date.